# How to install Jython standard library into Confluence?

Tags: jython, confluence

I'm starting to integrate some Jython code into our Confluence wiki and I'd like to install the Jython standard lib -- the Jython plugin from Atlassian apparently is only the base Jython install, so I need to make a Jar with the Jython library and get it up onto the server (our server is hosted, btw).  So, where can I put that jar -- or where to I tell the service folks to put it?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Jython on the server and set the JYTHONPATH environment variable to point to the Jython lib directory.  We're running Confluence on Tomcat on Solaris and set JYTHONPATH=path_to_jython_install/Lib in setenv.sh.  Setenv.sh is called by catalina.sh, which is called by start-confluence.sh.

Here's a link that explains this:  https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SCRP/How+to+use+Jython+libraries?focusedCommentId=31916077#comment-31916077